# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException no Reflection de parâmetros do Java 8

Tags: java, reflexão, java-8

Eu estava fazendo um código com reflection no Java 8 quando me deparei com um comportamento estranho - Um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` inesperado. Com base nisso, eu decidi criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.

Primeiramente observe este código:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class BuggyReflection {
    public class Test {
        public Test(Class k) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (Constructor<?> ctor : Test.class.getConstructors()) {
            for (Parameter p : ctor.getParameters()) {
                System.out.println(p.getParameterizedType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
class BuggyReflection
class java.lang.Class
```

Agora, quando eu altero o tipo do parâmetro do construtor de `Class` para `Class<?>`:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class BuggyReflection {
    public class Test {
        public Test(Class<?> k) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (Constructor<?> ctor : Test.class.getConstructors()) {
            for (Parameter p : ctor.getParameters()) {
                System.out.println(p.getParameterizedType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Então ocorre uma exceção inesperada:

```
java.lang.Class<?>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getParameterizedType(Parameter.java:201)
    at BuggyReflection.main(BuggyReflection.java:14)
```

Estou fazendo alguma coisa errada? Não vejo sentido nenhum em ocorrer este erro.

Investigando mais um pouco com este código:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BuggyReflection {
    public class Test {
        public Test(Class k) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (Constructor<?> ctor : Test.class.getConstructors()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ctor.getGenericParameterTypes()) + ctor.getParameters().length);
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída, demonstrando que para a JVM há dois parâmetros no construtor (vez que é uma classe interna não-estática):

```
[class BuggyReflection, class java.lang.Class]2
```

Agora, se eu trocar o `Class` por `Class<?>`:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BuggyReflection {
    public class Test {
        public Test(Class<?> k) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (Constructor<?> ctor : Test.class.getConstructors()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ctor.getGenericParameterTypes()) + ctor.getParameters().length);
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado é no mínimo incoerente:

```
[java.lang.Class<?>]2
```

Eis as versões do java e do javac que estou usando:

```
C:\projetos>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25

C:\projetos>javac -fullversion
javac full version "1.8.0_25-b18"

C:\projetos>java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

C:\projetos>java -fullversion
java full version "1.8.0_40-b25"
```

Estou fortemente inclinado a acreditar que isso é um bug no Java, mas gostaria de saber se de fato estou fazendo algo errado ou se esta exceção é de alguma forma prevista (não achei nada a respeito na documentação).

Comment: Acho que é bug mesmo. Com o `getType()` funciona normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É um bug do Java:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5087240

Para contornar esse bug, é necessário verificar-se se o `Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes()` e o `Constructor.getParameters()` retornam arrays de tamanhos diferentes. Caso isso ocorra, é deduzido que existe o parâmetro implícito da classe externa faltando.